# highly sporadic validation error during training with multilayer perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, validation

I'm encountering an issue where a classifier I'm developing reports validation errors during training that span a wide range of values without consistently decreasing over time. Unfortunately, I'm new to ML and related topics and can't seem to diagnose the problem as a result.

The base code of the classifier comes from the theano deep_learning tutorials, specifically from the multilayer perceptron tutorial: [link](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/mlp.html#index-0)

I have changed the code from the tutorial in two ways:
(1) Altered the data being used
(2) Altered the topography of the MLP to account for a different number of input and output nodes

Here is an image of typical results: [image]

The data I'm using comes from a wine quality experiment: [link](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality)

**I would appreciate help understanding:**

(1) Why this is happening
(2) How I should go about fixing it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The amount of wiggle in your loss is related to the size of your batch.
If you compute the loss over a larger batch size you should see a smoothened loss function. This means that if your validation loss was calculated on a larger batchsize, you won't see the sporadicity that you observe.

Here is an excerpt from Stanford's CNN course notes

> The amount of “wiggle” in the loss is related to the batch size. When
>   the batch size is 1, the wiggle will be relatively high. When the
>   batch size is the full dataset, the wiggle will be minimal because
>   every gradient update should be improving the loss function
>   monotonically (unless the learning rate is set too high).

You can also check out this link which gives some more insight on training loss:
http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue due to lack of centering of column features, once I did that my validation error smoothed out.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this ?

Answer (score -1):

The issue I was having was that my learning rate was too high. I reduced it from .01 to .001 and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in another answer, lowering the learning rate until the validation error stabilizes has worked for me. Also normalizing/standardizing input data (e.g. using sci-kit preprocessing) prior to running the model should help too!